# Search and replace inside of square brackets

Tags: bash, sed

I've gone over many threads and tried different settings to perform search and replace using Sed and AWK, however, I was not that successful.

I need to replace `#relayhost = [mailserver.isp.tld]` with `relayhost = [smtp.mydomain.com]`.

I used below two commands but both really do not provide required result.

```
sed -i 's/#relayhost = [mailserver.isp.tld]/relayhost = [smtp.mydomain.com]/g' /etc/postfix/main.cf.
```

Also tried

```
sed -e '0,/#relayhost = [mailserver.isp.tld]/{//i\[smtp.mydomain.com]' -e '}' /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

I need to uncomment the line and change the content side the square brackets. Any suggestions why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `[]` in the pattern, as well as other characters that have special meaning in regular expressions, in this example the `.`:

```
sed -i 's/#relayhost = \[mailserver\.isp\.tld\]/relayhost = [smtp.mydomain.com]/' /etc/postfix/main.cf.
```

As a side note, I dropped the `/g` flag, you don't need it.

See also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29626460#29626460) for dealing with escaping metacharacters in patterns.

Comment: sed operates on regexps, not strings, so you need to escape any RE metacharacters in the search field of your command. In this specific case that's just the `.`s but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29626460#29626460 for how to deal with that in general.